# How to append a span to a <li> if a submenu exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to build a responsive navigation and want to append a <span> to all top level menu items *that* contain a submenu <ul>. For some reason this just appends the span to all items, can anybody advise as to why?

Here's the markup:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul class="nav-submenu">
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">Submenu item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-submenu-item">
                    <a href="#">Submenu item 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

So you can see the first item has a dropdown, and I want to dynamically append a span element to each <li> that contains a submenu.

And the script (jQuery):

```
$.each($('.nav-item'), function (index, value) {
    if ($('.nav-item').children('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).append($('<span class="nav-click"></span>'));
    }
});
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is all you need:

```
$('.nav-item:has(ul)').append('<span class="nav-click" />');
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ucebus/2/edit)**</kbd>

using `:has` or `.has()` will be much more fun than all this `$.each` looping. The class looping is already done using class as selector cause returns a collection of your desired elements additionally filtered by `has`, all in one line.

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/has/

In the case you're planning to have a *multi-sub-level* list use:

```
$('nav li:has(ul)').append('<span class="nav-click" />');
```

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ucebus/4/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this! Would this apply the span class for each &lt;ul&gt; though? Let's say there was a 3 tier menu?

Comment: @Halcyon21 in that case use `$('nav li:has(ul)').prepend('<span class="nav-click" />');`  http://jsbin.com/ucebus/4/edit

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using .has() instead of the pseudo selector? I'd like to use my classes as much as possible :-)

Comment: @Halcyon21 Sure!, have you tried? `$('nav li').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click" />');`

Comment: $('.nav-item').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"></span>'); works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each($('.nav-item'), function (index, value) {
    if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).append($('<span class="nav-click"></span>'));
    }
});
```

You have problem in this line:

```
if ($('.nav-item').children('ul').length > 0) {
```

this will always select first `.nav-item` found

you need to use `this` instead as you are looping through each `.nav-item`

```
if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
```

Comment: I was so close! Thank you, will accept this when timer runs out.